# Google App Engine servlet throws java.security.AccessControlException using Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, servlets, eclipse-plugin

I'm running a Java servlet on Google App Engine, which runs an XQuery script using kawa, redirects to a JSP and displays the answer

```
package com.myserver.servlet;

import gnu.xquery.lang.XQuery;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class XQueryTest extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        XQuery xQuery = new XQuery();
        Object result = new String("");     
        try {
            String realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("./XQueryTest.xquery");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(realPath); 
            result = xQuery.eval(fileReader);
            request.setAttribute("xQueryTest", result.toString());              
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/XQueryTest.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);           
    }
}
```

This runs fine on appspot.com and using the dev_appserver command, but running the same servlet in Eclipse using the plugin throws a java.security.AccessControlException

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/home/myuser/eclipse/jee-latest/eclipse" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:442)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:844)
    at java.io.File.toURI(File.java:732)
    at gnu.text.FilePath.toUri(FilePath.java:245)
    at gnu.text.FilePath.toUri(FilePath.java:265)
    at gnu.text.Path.toURI(Path.java:279)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.fixupStaticBaseUri(XQParser.java:99)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.getStaticBaseUri(XQParser.java:132)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.wrapWithBaseUri(XQParser.java:2722)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parseXMLConstructor(XQParser.java:2540)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parseMaybePrimaryExpr(XQParser.java:2954)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parsePrimaryExpr(XQParser.java:2181)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parseStepExpr(XQParser.java:2101)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parsePathExpr(XQParser.java:1816)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parseIntersectExceptExpr(XQParser.java:1779)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parseUnionExpr(XQParser.java:1763)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parseUnaryExpr(XQParser.java:1756)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parseBinaryExpr(XQParser.java:1671)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parseExprSingle(XQParser.java:1664)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parseExpr(XQParser.java:1636)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parseIfExpr(XQParser.java:3145)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parseExprSingle(XQParser.java:1652)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parseExpr(XQParser.java:1636)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parseEnclosedExpr(XQParser.java:2413)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parseFunctionDefinition(XQParser.java:3620)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQParser.parse(XQParser.java:3784)
    at gnu.xquery.lang.XQuery.parse(XQuery.java:147)
    at gnu.expr.Language.parse(Language.java:702)
    at gnu.expr.Language.parse(Language.java:656)
    at gnu.expr.Language.eval(Language.java:1122)
    at gnu.expr.Language.eval(Language.java:1063)
    at gnu.expr.Language.eval(Language.java:1053)
    at com.myserver.servlet.XQueryTest.doGet(XQueryTest.java:30)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I had a theory that the security policy of the JRE running eclipse was causing the problem, but adding the permission to java.policy and javaws.policy for the JRE in eclipse.ini made no difference.

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

I'm using eclipse oxygen and version 1.0.3.201704111618 of the Google Cloud Platform plugin
This worked fine in eclipse Mars and Java 1.7

What changes should I make to let the servlet run correctly in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/home/myuser/eclipse/jee-latest/eclipse` looks like where you started your Eclipse IDE. If that's the case, then for now, that directory becomes a working directory of the local dev server of the Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse (CT4E) plugin. The problem might be that XQuery internally tries to access files outside the servlet context because XQuery may be basing off of the Eclipse working directory. Can you try the following workaround to set a correct working directory to see if it solves the problem?

[Cannot access file using relative path in local test when developing Google App Engine applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618900/cannot-access-file-using-relative-path-in-local-test-when-developing-google-app/43639428#43639428)

**UPDATE: We fixed CT4E to automatically set the working directory properly (unless you run multiple projects in a single local server), and you won't need the workaround once the fixed version rolls out.**

Comment: that;s fixed the issue, thanks. I can start the server from eclipse and connect to it without any issues